# Cryptsetup/LUKS destroyed my data when I tried to remove encryption. Why?

Tags: luks

Cryptsetup/LUKS2 destroyed my data when I tried to remove encryption, Why?

I'm Using Cryptsetup 2.3.3. I was experimenting with LUKS (in a VM, thankfully)
and had an ext4 filesystem on a LUKS2 encrypted partition. I decided to
test out LUKS's ability to non-destructively remove encryption from a block device
I ran `cryptsetup reencrypt --decrypt` and got an error I must pass in a header.
Since I do not use a detached header, I passed in the device so it can read the header
off of it. The decryption gave a "standard" warning:

```
WARNING!
========
Unable to decide if device /tmp/file is activated or not.
Are you sure you want to proceed with reencryption in offline mode?
It may lead to data corruption if the device is actually activated.
To run reencryption in online mode, use --active-name parameter instead.
```

and then procceded to decrypt without reporting any error... then the data was lost.

What I expected is for the ext4 system formerly inside the LUKS2 device to become
visible to the OS, just as if I'd formatted the partition with ext4 to begin with.
But `blkid` still detected the partition as  `TYPE="crypto_LUKS"`.
I then tried to open the partition with luks, thinking it may have actually done nothing,
and the data was still there. But after entering the passphrase I got the error

```
Keyslot open failed.
No usable keyslot is available.
```

and `luksDumps` showed no active keyslots.

**Why did cryptsetup destroy my data?**

Answer (score 3):

`cryptsetup`'s decryption of LUKS2 device is badly documented and includes several
incredibly bad design choices which help you destroy your data.

For the problem descirbed in OP, the issue is that it `cryptsetup` assumes you're
using a detached header, but doesn't clearly state it anywhere. It doesn't include
any basic sanity checks to stop you from making this error and their tests don't cover
this scenario.

If you check, the [tests](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/blob/master/tests/luks2-reencryption-test) for this all use a device created with a detached header.
It also looks like they only test online decryption, even though the command allows
offline decryption.

I've tested decryption for LUKS2 device with detached header and it worked. After decryption, the partition was detected as being formatted with an ext4 filesystem.

Note that it would be trivial for cryptsetup to check that the device already has
a header and at least warn the user that's the case. In the offline case, it could
also easily determine that the encrypted block device was also passed in as the
`--header` argument and either handle this gracefully, or refuse to proceed. But
it does neither.

Decryption (possible only in offline mode) works for LUKS1,but for that you
don't use `cryptsetup reencrypt --decrypt` (which is confusing usage in itself), but instead
need to use a separate command called `cryptsetup-reencrypt`. This command
supports LUKS1, but not LUKS2, naturally. To make things worse, at least on fedora this command isn't packaged as part of `cryptsetup`, but as a separate package `cryptsetup-reencrypt` which isn't installed by default.

In summary:

- As of 2.3.3, you can't directly decrypt a LUKS2 drive unless you use a detached header.
  Passing a device that has a header as the
  `--header` argument raise no error, and cryptsetup will then proceed to quietly destroy your data.
- You could probably convert from luks2 to luks1, and then use the seperate `cryptsetup-reencrypt` command to decrypt. I haven't tested this, but it should work.

I tried reporting this issue upstream, but gitlab prevents users who try to register with some anonnymity.